# AsyncSnapshot<...> is not subtype AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>, AsyncWidgetBuilder error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a special class for handling responses from resources(`RepositoryResponse` class).

```
class RepositoryBuilder<T extends RepositoryResponse> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<T> future;
  final AsyncWidgetBuilder<T> builder;

  const RepositoryBuilder({this.future, this.builder});

  @override
  _RepositoryBuilderState createState() => _RepositoryBuilderState<T>();
}

class _RepositoryBuilderState<T extends RepositoryResponse> extends State<RepositoryBuilder> {
  Future<T> future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    future = widget.future;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<T>(future: future, builder: widget.builder);
  }
}
```

This is a part of one of the screens on my application:

```
RepositoryBuilder<RepositoryResponse<Set<Invoice>>>(
          future: orderRepository.fetchInvoices(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              return snapshot.data.apiData.isEmpty
                ? SomeWidget()
                : AnotherWidget();
            }
          },
        )
```

So, end of the day, this is the error, which is make no sense for me:

> The following assertion was thrown building `RepositoryBuilder<RepositoryResponse<Set<Invoice>>>(dirty, state: _RepositoryBuilderState<RepositoryResponse<Set<Invoice>>>#e23da)`:
>   type '`(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<RepositoryResponse<Set<Invoice>>>) => Widget`' is not a subtype of type '`(BuildContext, AsyncSnapshot<RepositoryResponse<dynamic>>) => Widget`'

So, how on the earth `Object<A>` can't be subtype of `Object<dynamic>`?